# Restart a java application for linux and windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, restart, processbuilder

I have a java application when there is a update it should restart . how can i automatically  restart the java application again .

I tried using a Process builder to restart.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.directory(new File(workingDir));
builder.start();
System.exit(0);
```

However when i check the applications running the earlier process was still running.

Comment: Does the app. have a GUI?

Comment: For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix & provides both auto & programmatically controlled update.

Answer (score 2):

Put your process restarting logic in a `separate thread` and register it as `shutdown hook`.

Perhaps you can give make this shutdown hook thread `daemon` and put some sleep in the main thread. If process does not restart in the given time them simply exit the application or else application will restart and let this (main) process close.

Also for starting new process you may want to consider

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(yourProcess);
```

For windows you can do

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start yourProcess");
```

and for linux process starts detached by default so just executing the command with  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(yourProcess);` should do the trick.